# Job execution time of PBS script (serial job)

Tags: execution-time, pbs

I'm trying to figure out the execution time of a serial job that was done using `Portable Batch System` (PBS). Is that information in the output file (task.o*), under Resources in the Epilogue section? Is it `walltime`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sometimes walltime includes both the time your program last + the time of being accepted
by the server in order to start running, i think. you can use:

```
time ./executable
```

where executable is the name of your executable and 'time' a command from linux. Then
you can see the time your simulation lasts in the output file.